# adding labels to only some of the data points

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot with labels:

> ```
> plot(data$y) 
> text(data$y,  labels = data$col1)
> ```

[image]

Now, what I want is to keep the label for only top 5 values (data points). How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?text`, we read that "Labels whose `x`, `y` or `labels` value is `NA` are omitted from the plot."

So all you need to do is build a vector that is `NA` for points you don't want to plot:

```
plot(data$y) 
text(data$y,  labels = ifelse(data$y > 50000, data$col1, NA))
```